# IF Else condition in a Trigger Fails to Detect NULL Value for FirstConnectionDatetime Parameter in before Update Statement

Tags: mariadb

I have a after update MariaDB trigger set up to perform certain actions based on the value of `FirstConnectionDatetime` in the `CustomerPurchases` table. However, I noticed that the trigger condition `IF NEW.FirstConnectionDatetime IS NOT NULL` is incorrectly evaluating to true even when I do not provide the `FirstConnectionDatetime` parameter in the update statement (thus it should be NULL). This unexpected behavior is causing issues in my database operations.

Answer (score 0):

> when I do not provide the FirstConnectionDatetime parameter in the update statement (thus it should be NULL)

Let's imagine that there is no a column in the UPDATE query. In this case the value before UPDATE and the value after it is the same. And both `OLD.column` and `NEW.column` are equal to this value.

`OLD.column` contains the value before UPDATE, `NEW.column` accordingly contains the value after UPDATE executed successfully. And none of them stores the value provided (or NULL if not provided) in the query!

It seems that you confuse `NEW.column` value and the value which is returned by `VALUES(column)` function.